# Angular array says its an object?

Tags: angular

I have a demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7vavy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have a simple function that creates an array of objects.

If I do a `typeof` on the array it says it's an object.

I'm I doing something wrong, is it an object or array, I need t to be an array

```
createData() {
    this.testData = [];
    console.log(typeof(this.testData));
    for(let n:number=0; n<=this.dates.length-1;n++){
      for(let i:number= 0; i<=4; i++){
        this.testData[i] = {
          data_1: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
          data_2: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
          data_3: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
          data_4: Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min)),
          date: this.dates[i]
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.testData)
    console.log(typeof(this.testData));
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because an array, strictly speaking, *is* an object. Just a very complex one.

`Array.isArray(val)` will tell you if an *object* is an *array*.